# Have awareness and consciousness been conflated in philosophical debate on consciousness?

Tags: consciousness, dennett, awareness, panpsychism

These seem to be used interchangeably on both sides of the consciousness debate, for example Dennett and Nagel. Leaving consciousness aside, it seems to me that awareness is different. A living thing might be aware of something and behave accordingly, but not be conscious. This is answered in response to another question here asked by Joseph Weismann answered by iphigenie.